# Assign Roles to my PHP Session?

Tags: php

Currently, I have a php script that checks if the user is logged in. If they are, the page loads. If they aren't, it redirects to the login page. I have achieved that, but now, I want to only allow users with a certain role to be able to view the page, not just be logged in. In my **phpro_users** table in **phpro_auth** database, I've added an additional column titled "role". I want users that are assigned, say for example, the role of "admin" to be able to view the page. In conclusion, I am trying to modify my script, which currently checks for a user to be logged in, to also check for a role. How can I achieve this? My script is as follows:

```
<?php

/*** begin the session ***/
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    $message = header("Location: http://localhost/correspondence/prologin/index.php");
}
else
{
    try
    {
        /*** connect to database ***/
        /*** mysql hostname ***/
        $mysql_hostname = 'localhost';

        /*** mysql username ***/
        $mysql_username = 'root';

        /*** mysql password ***/
        $mysql_password = '';

        /*** database name ***/
        $mysql_dbname = 'phpro_auth';


        /*** select the users name from the database ***/
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
        /*** $message = a message saying we have connected ***/

        /*** set the error mode to excptions ***/
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        /*** prepare the insert ***/
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT phpro_username FROM phpro_users 
        WHERE phpro_user_id = :phpro_user_id");

        /*** bind the parameters ***/
        $stmt->bindParam(':phpro_user_id', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

        /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
        $stmt->execute();

        /*** check for a result ***/
        $phpro_username = $stmt->fetchColumn();

        /*** if we have no something is wrong ***/
        if($phpro_username == false)
        {
            $message = 'Access Error';
        }
        else
        {
            $message = 'Welcome '.$phpro_username;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        /*** if we are here, something is wrong in the database ***/
        $message = 'We are unable to process your request. Please try again later"';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: just add another condition to the first if - check if session role is set and if it equals whatever role it should be

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Well, you already have a condtion there to check if a key is set in session, so you can reuse that. And checking if something equals something is just as easy as it sounds. Glhf :)

Comment: Make sure you are selecting the role column as well? Otherwise you will not have the column data to evaluate if the user has a certain role or not.

Comment: Yeah as @Terry says you have to make sure you add the role to the session in your successful login code

Answer (score 1):

Since you added a new column, You should get the new value:

```
`$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT phpro_username, phpro_auth  FROM phpro_users WHERE phpro_user_id = :phpro_user_id);`
```

And then use

```
if($row = $stmt -> fetch_assoc()) {
  if($row['phpro_auth'] == 'admin') {
    $massage = 'Welcome ,'.$row['phpro_username'];
  } else {
    $massage = 'Not authorized';
} else {
  $massage = 'Access Error';
}
```

to give the user feedback why he cant access your site. The first if-statement in my code will do the same yours did.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to check the corresponding value in the table, to see if it returns an admin user...

```
if($phpro_username == false && $phpro_rol == "admin")//or the correct data to be returned...
        {
            $message = 'Access Error';
        }
```